# PrintedPdfDocument pdf images size too large on Android 5

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, android-5.0-lollipop, pdfrenderer

I'm creating pdf pages in my Android App.
In order to keep compatibility to older devices using Kitkat (API 19) I used the workflow with `PrintedPdfDocument` and `PdfDocument.Page`
instead of the `PdfRenderer` (which requires API 21)

The problem is, that images seem to be stored uncompressed. My test image (having about 2000x700 px) is about 3Mb large.

As far as I can see this only happens on Android 5. Later versions produce smaller (compressed) images (around 200kb).

Unfortunately I can't find many ways configuring the output.

My print attributes look like this:

```
PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
    .setMediaSize(mediaSize)
    .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
    .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
    .build();
```

So except for setting to COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME I don't see anything I could try.

Does anyone have any idea? The only way to me would be looking for the API leve, using the newer `PdfRenderer` for API 21+ and my original solution for Kitkat.

Is there a better way instead of two different workflows?

Comment: `PdfRenderer` does not create PDF files. It renders PDF files. And while the Android printing framework has classes for creating PDFs, it is designed for printing, not for saving to files, and so the file size may not be a key criterion. Use iText 5 or other dedicated PDF generation libraries.

Comment: So you mean, it's just "luck" it works for later Android versions?

Comment: Oh, they may have legitimately changed it. The reasons for changing would not be to create smaller PDF *files*, since this code is not designed for files. However, a smaller PDF means faster delivery to a printer (less bandwidth). My point is that you are using code for a use case (generating PDF files) that lies outside that code's developers' use case (printing content). Do not complain when your use case is not met.

Comment: Okay, I get it. However it seems to be the only way for pdf creation on Android 4.4. Is that correct?

Comment: Use iText 5 or other commercial libraries for PDF creation, on various versions of Android.

Comment: Just to avoid a misunderstanding. I'm currently using the PdfDocument not the PdfRenderer. The PdfDocument creates that huge (image) files in pdfs for Android 5.
So as I understand your comment, you mean I shouldn't switch to PdfRenderer - even though it is newer? Or was there a misunderstanding? It was just my hope the newer API would help. After all they have more ways for customisation!

Comment: "So as I understand your comment, you mean I shouldn't switch to PdfRenderer - even though it is newer?" -- it is newer, but **it does not create PDF files**. It renders them, by converting pages to bitmaps for display purposes (e.g., print preview).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just wanted to be sure!

Comment: You can save the bitmap into a compressed format like png using Bitmap.compress method. I tested it. It made a 340 KB png file instead of an 18 MB PDF! Then  you can use a library like apwlibrary to convert the image into a pdf file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've some other bugs to fix but I gonna try this soon.